# make .htaccess redirect case sensitive

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, tomcat

I need to redirect to folders from port 80 to 8080
1. Default index to /somename 
2. /admin to /somename

I tried a .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect / http://example.com:8080/somename
Redirect /admin http://example.com:8080/someAdmin
```

But i'm running JSP so the folder name i used is someAdmin (note A uppercase)
It's impossible for me to change the path in my code (sorry about it)

**Problem**
So because of this i'm getting error page (CASE sEnSiTive) redirection
(Automatically it converts to small case in browser)

**AddOn**
I'll be happy if it .htaccess could mask 8080 port from user via reverse proxy.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/somefolder%{REQUEST_URI}
Redirect /admin http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/someAdmin
```

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd that `Redirect` is behaving like that. I don't have an Apache instance handy right now to verify that mod_alias is supposed to behave like that, but if it's not going to respect case in a target location, then I suppose just use mod_rewrite, since you're loading it anyway:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com:8080/somename [R,L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ http://example.com:8080/someAdmin [R,L]
```

For reverse proxying, it looks like you'd want to proxy instead of, as opposed to in addition to, the redirects?

For what you need, `ProxyPass` would work just fine, but it doesn't play nice with .htaccess.  If you have the option, don't config this in .htaccess, use `ProxyPass` instead.  If you don't, then mod_rewrite should do the trick:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ http://example.com:8080/someAdmin$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:8080/somename/$1 [R,L]
```